# Jquery Parsing a div

Tags: jquery

Trying to parse some data with Jquery. I need to put the contents of this:

```
<div>
    <div id='1' class='data'>
    <td>Data1</td>
    <td>Data1</td>
    </div>

    <div id='2' class='data'>
    <td>Data2</td>
    <td>Data2</td>
    </div>
</div>
```

Into the respective row ids

```
<tr id='row_1'>
</tr>

<tr id='row_2'>
</tr>
```

The catch is the td's are returned from an ajax get call for a page, so I need to work with the return object 'data'. Here is my code so far:

```
success: function(data) {
$("<div />").html(data).find(".data").each(function(data){
    $("#row_" + $(this).attr("id")).html($(this).html())
})   
},
```

`$(this).attr('id')` is returning the proper id. `$(this).html()` is empty.

EDIT:

This works:

```
    $("<div />").html(data).find(".data").each(function(){

    $('#row_' + $(this).attr('id')).html($(this).html());

});
```

And the page:

```
<div>

    <table> 
     <tr id='1' class='data'>
    <td>Data1</td>
    <td>Data1</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
    <tr id='2' class='data'>
    <td>Data2</td>
    <td>Data2</td>
    </tr>
    </table>


</div>
```

Comment: Why are you pseudo-escaping quotes like that? `$(\"<div />\")` is not syntactically valid JavaScript.

Comment: Oh im sorry please done mind that. It is being echoed by php. I'll edit that out.

Comment: Have you tried updating your data to be valid html? When I tried it in Chrome it didn't like having td elements as children of divs (it kept the text content but not the td tags - check the output from `console.log($("<div />").html(data).html())`).

Comment: thanks that was a big part of the problem

Answer (score 2):

```
$(data).find('.data').each(function(){
  var id = this.id;
  $('#row_'+id).html($(this).html());
})
```

Comment: @MattBall ... i skipped that part `$("<div />").html(data)`... ;

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function() {
$('table tr').each(function() {
  var tr_id = $(this).attr('id'); // id from each tr
  $('#row_'+ tr_id).html($(this).html());
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>

    <table> 
     <tr id='1' class='data'>
    <td>Data1</td>
    <td>Data1</td>
    </tr>
    </table>

    <table>
    <tr id='2' class='data'>
    <td>Data2</td>
    <td>Data2</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
    <tr id='row_1'></tr>
    <tr id='row_2'></tr>
    </table>

</div>
```